# What is the most common method to find a group for a Flashpoint?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So I just got my first empire Flashpoint, a 2 player job. Since it starts from the fleet, I don't really want to just ask in fleet general chat if anyone wants to do the quest with me. Is there a better way to find groups for Flashpoints? Such as a built in system that I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience, being in the fleet and going "/1 [my class] LFG [name of flashpoint]" works reasonably well.

Alternately, paying attention to General and responding when someone goes "[flashpoint] group LF[number]M" for much the same reason.

**EDIT**: [Update 1.3 introduced the Group Finder Queue](http://www.swtor.com/gameupdates/1.3-allies), and gives out bonus commendations once a day for using it. Learn it. Use it. The more people who use it well, the better it works.

Answer (score 6):

Gather in the flashpoint location and flag yourself in `/who` or in the Social window (Press "O") as LFG, you can also leave a short note there (E.g., "LFG Hammer" or just "hammer"). You can then search for people with LFG tags. It's nice tool, but it's a shame not many people use it.

Comment: Since not many people use it, it's not very useful.

Comment: not very useful **yet**, as I'm sure most people are unaware of it's existence. only way to change that is get the word out :P

Comment: For what it's worth I did see an explanation of how to do this in a load screen "tip" a few days ago. If enough people read those maybe it'll become more commonly used.

Comment: Just to provide a current perspective over a year later -- virtually no one uses this still, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Most people post in general, so I would just do it.  It's effective.

Sometimes you'll also find people waiting outside the start area for the quest, and you can invite them or vice-versa.  It's particularly unambiguous if you or they have the purple LFG icon hovering above you by setting your status in the `/who` list, as Krazer notes.  I've noticed that most people don't use the LFG flag, unfortunately..

See [Andrzej's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/74881/6066) for a description of the new Group Finder tool, which is another option.

Answer (score 3):

With the recent addition of patch 1.3, the [Group Finder](http://www.swtor.com/blog/guide-group-finder) is by far the easiest/most effective way to get groups together for flashpoints (both heroic and normal), story-mode Operations, and heroic quests on planets.

It's available from level 10 onwards as a tab next to the minimap.  See the linked official guide for full details.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the relative class balances queuing (and server pop), of course.  You only have to wait if your class is overrepresented - otherwise, the queue will pop instantly if the other people are already there.  On my tank, it's popped instantly every time :)

Comment: It is. My tank character tends to get into queues much quicker than my DPS alt.

Comment: Still, it's worth adding that this doesn't *preclude* you from asking in General chat or forming up your own group manually while queued in the background.  If the queue does pop in this situation it's a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

Posting in channels can be an effective way of finding groups (though not as ideal as an automatic queueing system or a commonly used /who system). Other games that do have these more effective systems still manage groups with this method.

That said, a piece of advice: If you are partied with no one else, but are willing to start a party, post with "LFM" instead of "LFG". People will be more likely to send you a tell if they too are looking.